# flutter firebase integration leveled/db file not found error

Tags: ios, firebase, dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Am trying to build an iOS app with firebase database!
its a flutter app.
When I try to build the app for iOS device or simulator, am getting below error

/Users/dsp/Development/mia_flutter/ios/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/Firebase/Database/third_party/Wrap-leveldb/APLevelDB.mm:54:9: fatal error: 'leveldb/db.h' file not found

## import "leveldb/db.h"

if I change the leveldb to leveled-library its working fine. Its working fine in android:

Below is My pub spec.yaml:

dependencies:

flutter:

```
   sdk: flutter
```

firebase_admob: ^0.5.4+1

flutter_facebook_login: "^1.1.1"

cloud_firestore: ^0.7.3

firebase_auth: "^0.5.11"

Comment: how about check this link?? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55962172/8912043 I hope to U solve it