# How to fix 'firebase_auth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.h' file not found in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, plugins, flutter, header

I tried to run flutter project in Xcode through running `runner.xcworkspace` file. once it's run I get this error:

> `firebase_auth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.h` file not found

I tried to change the state of headers to public but this didn't change anything.

**Error Page:**

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MpfHsbVzuPXpZpl1ZhNZmTAP-bgQ5Mt4/view?usp=sharing]

**Flutter Doctor:**

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yQzMZA9W3ue4LM1Uwu8H2wBMic3WVWyt/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: Will this answr your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59592295/flutter-build-failed-useragent-h-file-not-found?noredirect=1#comment107294554_59592295?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem all day long. I ended up having to bump my version of Firebase_Auth to the latest, which for me at the moment is: `^0.15.3`, which then forced me to have to upgrade Flutter as well.

Did the typical

`Delete PodFile and PodFile.lock`
`Flutter Clean`
`pod install`

I'm using Mac, so I also had to update my Xcode to `11.3`. Then needed to update Mac OS to `Catalina`.

Lot's of work, but this got me to a successful build.
Hopefully, something in here helps others dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Update your pod. Your pod is not on the latest version

Answer (score 1):

try this

- `pod install` command in ios folder
- `xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator11.2 -scheme Runner -workspace Runner.xcworkspace`

Answer (score 0):

Updating pod was not enough for me.

I need to replace the content of my Podfile with Podfile-ios-objc.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/templates/cocoapods/Podfile-ios-objc

Than it worked.

Answer (score 0):

So non of this worked for me. After a while, I finally figured how to make it work.
My project name has an underscore ie: project_name, so I changed it to projectname. And I realised my package id is still the same either ways hence somehow there is a conflict with how firebase references files. Not sure and don't know why this is happening.