# Flutter build failed 'UserAgent.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, flutter, cocoapods

Project cannot build or debug with firebase_crashlytics. In my mac I've updated to Flutter latest but the machine we are deploying the app have lower version (Flutter 1.9.1 hotfix-5). So I tried below things:

- `flutter pub cache repair`
- `flutter clean`
- deleting Podfile.lock and `ios/pod install`

But no luck.

```
#import "UserAgent.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Is there any solution without upgrading flutter for the time being?

Comment: Checkout my answer to the problem here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60645357/4412850

Answer (score 23):

I was almost there, I think even if I clean the flutter and `pod install` will not clear everything. I just had to do below steps:

- `flutter clean`
- Delete Podfile.lock
- `cd ios`
- `pod deintegrate` `// or you can do **cd ios/pod deintegrate** without above step`
- `pod install`

If this still didnt work. Please close `.xcworkspace` and podfile.lock then do last two step again and open newly generated `.xcworkspace` and Product -> build.

*If not yet fixed  please add a comment below (I have dealt lot of these problems).*

Check here are created issues for this: [issue 1 with firestore](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35670) and [issue 2 with crashlytics](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35635).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the [firestore issue ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35670#issuecomment-593422250), fixing the version of the firebase core to 0.4.4 instead of using 0.4.4+2 fixed the issue:

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_core: 0.4.4
```

Add this along with your existing `firebase_auth` dependency.

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution

just comment or import and put this code below it should look like this

```
#import "FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h"
// #import "UserAgent.h"
// Generated file, do not edit

#define LIBRARY_VERSION @"0.4.4-2"
#define LIBRARY_NAME @"flutter-fire-core"
```